# Как настроить работу работу с исходниками ASP .NET Core в Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Прохожу курс по ASP .NET Core, там разбирается жизненный цикл приложения на примере сэмпла из репозитория с исходным кодом самого aspnetcore. Объясняется как его склонировать и настроить, но у меня эти инструкции сломались еще на полпути.

Погуглив, я добился некоторого прогресса: вроде уже запускается VS, но появляется сообщение "One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly. Please see the Output Window for details" а сами ошибки такие:

> G:\tmp\2\aspnetcore\src\Http\Routing\test\testassets\Benchmarks\Benchmarks.csproj : error  : The project file cannot be opened. Version 6.0.100-alpha.1.20472.11 of the .NET Core SDK requires at least version 16.8.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 16.7.0.37604. Change the .NET Core SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.

> G:\tmp\2\aspnetcore\src\SiteExtensions\LoggingBranch\LB.csproj : error  : Specified condition " $(IsTargetingPackBuilding) " evaluates to "" instead of a boolean.  G:\tmp\2\aspnetcore\src\SiteExtensions\LoggingBranch\LB.csproj

Как я делал: у меня установлен гит и Node.js версии 12.16.2

1. Склонировал репо `git clone --recursive https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore`, клонировал в папку G:\tmp\2 чтобы не было русских символов и пробелов в пути
2. VS у меня уже установлена, но чтобы настроить ее нужным образом, я из папки `aspnetcore\eng\scripts` запустил через PowerShell скрипт `InstallVisualStudio.ps1 -edition community`
3. Далее из папки `aspnetcore` через обычную командную строку запустил скрипт `restore` чтобы восстановить зависимости. Ошибок не было
4. Теперь пришло время открыть солюшен `aspnetcore\src\Mvc\Mvc.slnf`. В курсе он назывался просто Mvc.sln, и для открытия говорили пользоваться скриптом `startvs` из папки `aspnetcore`.

Ну и вот после этих шагов у меня получились ошибки сверху. В связи с этим вопросы: то, что я уже сделал - правильно ли это? И если правильно, то как мне тогда понизить версию SDK, до какой? Файл `global.json` я нашел:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.100-alpha.1.20472.11"
  },
  "tools": {
    "dotnet": "6.0.100-alpha.1.20472.11",
    "runtimes": {
      "dotnet/x64": [
        "2.1.18",
        "$(MicrosoftNETCoreAppInternalPackageVersion)"
      ],
      "dotnet/x86": [
        "$(MicrosoftNETCoreAppInternalPackageVersion)"
      ],
      "aspnetcore/x64": [
        "3.1.4"
      ]
    },
    "Git": "2.22.0",
    "jdk": "11.0.3",
    "vs": {
      "version": "16.5",
      "components": [
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.17134"
      ]
    },
    "xcopy-msbuild": "16.5.0-alpha"
  },
  "msbuild-sdks": {
    "Yarn.MSBuild": "1.15.2",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk": "5.0.0-beta.20474.4",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Helix.Sdk": "5.0.0-beta.20474.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Я думаю у вас не устанвлены SDK для VS под Core Откройте Visual Studio Installer -> изменить стоит ли у вас тут галка ? http://joxi.ru/V2VBB9vhd4O602 если нет поставьте или устаните или установите SDK отдельно

Comment: @Pavel Popov Стоит SDK для Core, Framework 4.7.2, 4.8. Причем для Core я еще отдельно качал с сайта раньше и ставил, а не через инсталлер.

Comment: Если у Вас в курсе даны рекомендации воспользоваться той или иной консольной утилитой для создания шаблона проекта - то, скорее всего, в курсе описывается работа не с Visual Studio, а с Visual Studio Code. Там это обычный подход: чуть что - заныривать в командную строку.

Comment: @S.H. нет, там VS Community используется. Скрипт нужен чтобы доставить в студию компоненты нужные автоматически.

Comment: Ошибка гласит: _requires at least version 16.8.0 of MSBuild_. Я проверил у себя: MSBuild версии 16.6.5. Очевидно, что и у вас более низкая версия. Легко находится такое: [RoslynTools.MSBuild 16.8.0-preview3](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/roslyn-tools/package/nuget/RoslynTools.MSBuild). Или в самой Студии: Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features - ставим галочку Use previews of the .NET Core SDK.